# Error 60200 when testing Silent Network Authentication

Tags: twilio

I am trying to use [this guide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/sna-testing-guide) to test SNA with my personal phone on T-Mobile. I register my phone number via the self-service page on the Twilio console and make a POST call to the verification service in powershell to obtain the verification URL:

> Invoke-WebRequest
> "https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services/VA1234567890/Verifications"
> -Method POST -Body "To=%2B12155555555&Channel=sna" -Credential $cr

This results in a 400 error saying that the sna channel isn't recognized:

> {"code": 60200, "message": "Invalid parameter: Channel",
> "more_info":"https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/60200", "status": 400}

When I change the channel from 'sna' to 'sms' I get the text just fine from Twilio. Any idea how to fix SNA?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here -

Unfortunately that error means you still need to request access for the SNA channel to use the Live Test Number feature. Step 2 of the Getting Started guide has the link for the form you need to submit: https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/verify-sna-live-test-number#get-started

After you submit the form we usually can grant access within 24 hours - sorry for the inconvenience, we require the extra step to help stay compliant with underlying carriers!